# Update database on buttonclick with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have searched all over for this and cannot find a solution. I am still a beginner in both PHP and AJAX, so please bear with me.

I have a file fetch.php which generates content for my page index.html.
Fetch.php gets data from a MySQL database and adds it to my index page like this:

```
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
$str .= '<div class="task" id='.$res['tid'].'>
      <table>
              <tr>
                      <td>
                      <button class="btnDelete" data-id="'.$res['tid'].'">x</button>
                      </td>
                      <td>'.$res["name"].'</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>'. $res["task"].'</td></tr></table></div>';
}

echo $str;
```

The "tid" being my table index. Now, when I click the button with the data-id of 1, I want to delete the row with the tid of 1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.btnDelete').click(function() {
var recordid = $('.btnDelete').data('id');
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'remove.php',
  data: { 'id': recordid},
});
});
</script>
```

This sends the (supposed to) data-id to the following PHP.

```
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB);

 if (!$con) {
die("Can not connect: " .mysql_error());
}

$id = $_POST['recordid'];
$sql = "UPDATE tasks SET visible = 'hide' WHERE tid = $id ";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

My PHP files work, but nothing happens when I click the button?
Below is my complete HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    getStatus();

});

function getStatus() {

    $('div#data').load('fetch.php');
    setTimeout("getStatus()",300000);

}

</script>


 </head>

 <body>

    <div id="data"> 

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.btnDelete').click(function() {
    var recordid = $('.btnDelete').data('id');
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'remove.php',
      data: { 'id': recordid},
   });
});
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the AJAX to trigger on the buttonclick and send the data-id to remove.php?

This is not a duplicate, it is an AJAX question and not a MySQL question

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it is an AJAX question and not a MySQL question

Comment: The duplicate is about jQuery AJAX, not MySQL. Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

As your `AJAX` loads your `HTML` and injects it in to the page, you'll have to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event when binding.

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnDelete", function () {
    /** Your code here. **/
});
```

**Reading Material**

[Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: It is not working. It simply does nothing on button click